# Cannot find SameTime Local Server with port 59449

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, sametime

Hi I am working on SameTime Web Connect Api. I the help document they have written, you will see servlet with port number 59449. However when I run LotusNotes and SameTime I find the port closed. I am using 8.5 version. Can you please help me?

Thanks a lot.
Omkar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the Notes 8.5.x client has the setting startWebContainer set to false when installed. To enable the Sametime webapi you will need to change this setting and restart the client.

To manually resolve the issue:
Go to \Notes\framework\rcp\plugin_customization.ini
Set the value com.ibm.collaboration.realtime.webapi/startWebContainer=true
Restart the Notes Client.

Source: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21377828